# Server sent disconnect message type 2 (protocol error): "Too many authentication failures for root" Windows 7

Tags: git, windows-7, ssh, putty, tortoisegit

Yesteryday I was trying to get github working with a putty private key.

Obviously I did something naughty as now I can't connect to my own server (Ubuntu, external) using `TortoiseGit` and the previously working `.pkk` file.

```
 server sent disconnect message type 2 (protocol error): "Too many authentication failures for root"
```

[image]

Whilst trying to set up github I started ssh via eval "ssh-agent- -s" and then proceded to obviously fill up something with failures.

[image]

Who knew that you were meant to use `ssh -T git:@github.com` and not your github email address.

How can I now connect to my server and push my git repo?

Comment: It just occurred to me that this error should be on my server. Not on windows 7.

Comment: Does this help? http://superuser.com/questions/187779/too-many-authentication-failures-for-username

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred for my when I tried to push on a repo while the push-url was not correct in sourcetree. For some reason sourcetree prompted login dials which I clicked away several times. Appearantly it caused a login with my username and a blank password and caused this mess (the same problem as in Jamie Hutber's question)

I solved this by pushing the commits via the terminal:

```
$ git push -u
```

It forces me to enter my password again. After that, all was well again.